# Connect to specific Database Directly

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to connect to a specific database rather than just connect to a SQL Server?  There are a ton of databases and each time I have to search though the long list to find mind which is stupid.  There has to be a way to specify server\DBName right?  I searched the web but couldn't not find how to do this when trying to connect to server in SQL Server's connect dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about if Sql Server Management Studio can `use` a specific database when you connect to a server...

That is a setting per "login". In SSMS, edit the properties of your login (under security > logins) and on the "general" tab there is a "default database" drop down. It is probably set to master, you can set it to the database you want used by default on your next connection.

EDIT

Try something along these lines...

```
ALTER LOGIN login_name WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = database
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to do this against a host I don't control where my database is managed...so is there no way in that case?  Discountasp.net hosts my SQL Server for example.  The issue is it's a shared host so there are like 100s of databases when I connect to their main DB server...so it's a pain to have to scroll down and find it every time I connect

Comment: They show you all the other shared databases as options to use? Weird.

Comment: If they're showing you other peoples databases then you might want to change hosts. You can always type `USE MyDatabase` when you log in. Did you actually try the suggestion in this post? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to SQL Server Management Studio:

```
ssms.exe -S <SERVERNAME> -d <DATABASENAME> -U <USERNAME> -P <PASSWORD>
```

As per the comments, you can create a shortcut and set the params there.

This is the full help listing:

> ssms.exe [-S server_name[\instance_name]] [-d database] [-U user] [-P
>   password] [-E] [file_name[, file_name]] [/?]
>
> ```
> [-S The name of the SQL Server instance to which to connect]
> [-d The name of the SQL Server database to which to connect]
> [-E]    Use Windows Authentication to login to SQL Server
> [-U The name of the SQL Server login with which to connect]
> [-P The password associated with the login]
> [file_name[, file_name]] names of files to load
> [-nosplash] Supress splash screen
> [/?]    Displays this usage information
> ```

Comment: so where do you do this, in the shortcut?

Comment: Yes, just add the command-line parameters to an existing shortcut, or create a new one specifically for this connection.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, I would like to add that you can **filter out** the amount of databases that you see when you log in. It is still not the best solution to my own liking but it helps to speed up my database searching quest when going through databases hosted at a shared hosting provider.

Also, keep in mind that you need to do this every time you log in.

Step 1) Right after logging in to your named instance, right-click on *Databases* -> *Filter* -> *Filter Settings*

[image]

Step 2) Type in the name of your database in the *Value* field for the property *Name* then click *OK*

[image]

Step 3) Done. Now expand the *Databases* folder again and your database should appear very promptly and with no additional databases.

Additionally, instead of using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I also use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to quickly open and query through my databases. However, LINQPad isn't SQL Server Management Studio, so you'll have to get used to that.